# JMeters XPath2 Extractor always return default value

Tags: xpath, soap, jmeter

I'm trying to extract a value from SOAP response using XPath2 Extractor but it always return the default value.

My JMeter configuration are as following:

1. Master : 1 machine
2. Slave : 1 machine (if successful I need to setup
   10 slave machines.)
3. JMeter Version : 5.0

XML response looks like following:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <h:ResHeader xmlns:h="http://www.ssss.com/ResHeader/SSS" xmlns="http://www.SSS.com/ResHeader/SSS" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        ...
    </h:ResHeader>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <element  xmlns="http://www.SSS.com/xx/xx">
        ...
        <ServerSettingInfo>
            <ServerUrl>https://SomeServer.com/XX</ServerUrl>
            <UserName>SomeUser</UserName>
            <Password>SomePassword</Password>
        </ServerSettingInfo>
        ...
    </element>
  </s:Body>
 </s:Envelope>
```

I have tried following XPath expression :

1. //ServerSettingInfo/ServerUrl/text()
2. //ServerUrl/text()
3. /s:Envelope/s:Body/element/ServerSettingInfo/ServerUrl/test()
4. /s:Envelope/s:Body/element/ServerSettingInfo/ServerUrl
5. /s:Envelope/s:Body/element/ServerSettingInfo/@ServerUrl

NONE of the above XPath expression worked for me.

XPath2 Extractor settings are as following :

1. Apply to : Main Sample Only
2. Name of created variable : ServerURL
3. XPAth : //ServerUrl/text()
4. Match No. 0
5. Default Value : NotFound
6. Namespace alias list : EMPTY

Does anyone has any idea why XPath2 Extractor is not working??

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Starting from [JMeter 2.9](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-29-blazemeters-picks-top-two-feature-upgrades) by default JMeter slave engines send the results to the master using `StrippedBatch` mode
2. As per [JMeter Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#sendermode):

   > `Stripped` mode family strips `responseData` so this means that some Elements that rely on the previous `responseData` being available will not work.
   >   This is not really a problem as there is always a more efficient way to implement this feature.

Assuming above statements my expectation is that the issue should go away if you add the next line to *user.properties* file on the master and all the slaves:

```
mode=Standard
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up.

References:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [JMeter Properties Reference](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html)

---

Update: for some reason I was under impression that the error is related to distributed testing, if you cannot find `ServerUrl` text value using [XPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) even in non-distributed mode you can do it using [name()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/name) function like:

```
(//*[name() = 'ServerUrl'])/text()
```

Demo:

[image]

If it still doesn't work (i.e. you provided incomplete SOAP response structure) you can go for [local-name() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/local-name)

```
(//*[local-name() = 'ServerUrl'])/text()
```

Comment: thank you for the response, I have already tried it.It does not work.

Comment: Try out XPath query like `(//*[local-name() = 'ServerUrl'])/text()`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. `(//*[name() = 'ServerUrl'])/text()` works in XPath2 Tester but as soon as I insert this xPath query in Xpath2 Extractor it does not work. No result is shown for XPath Extractor in View Results Tree

Comment: HTTP Requests after that are also not executed.

Comment: What does *jmeter.log* say? A little hint: you can [increase JMeter log verbosity for extractors](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) by adding the next lint to *log4j2.xml* file `<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc" level="debug" />` . By the way, I cannot reproduce your issue using [the following XPath Extractor configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N27AD.png). Here is the [evidence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2V2re.png)

Comment: Okay, found the problem. ServerUrl is extracted with the XPath you gave me but value is store in this format : `http://[https://SSS.com/xxx/]/aa/` and because I'm using this URL in my next request **Malformed URL** occurs.

Comment: ServerURL returned from 1st request already has `https://` padded in it and JMeter pads http:// on its own. Hence URL is malformed for the 2nd request.

Comment: Put your `${ServerUrl}` variable into "Path" Section of the HTTP Request sampler and remove everything else (protocol, host, port, etc.) like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKcct.png)

Comment: @DmitriT, wouldn't it have been better to remove you answer and point to mine ? AFAIK, it's the most up to date and efficient way to use XPath extractors.

Comment: I don't see a lot of sense in doing this as: 1. my approach works. 2. even after correction your namespaces-based suggestion it's 3x times slower than mine despite the fact I'm using inefficient wildcard-deep-scan horrible query

Answer (score 2):

This works with [XPath2 Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath2_Extractor):

[image: XPath 2 Extractor]

Since you have namespaces, you need to add something in Namespace Alias List.

Use Xpath2 Tester in View Results Tree to extract list of namespace:

[image: XPath 2 Tester]

Then add for example in Namespace Alias List to choose a as an alias for 'http://www.SSS.com/xx/xx':

> a=http://www.SSS.com/xx/xx

Then you can use:

> //a:ServerUrl

**Note that if you have put http://www.SSS.com/xx/xx just to hide initial namespace, then of course you need to modify it to match the real namespace of ServerUrl element**

Note : Dmitri note on Distributed testing is unrelated to your problem.

Comment: it shows `null=http://xxxx.com/xx/xx` in the name space. what do I do if alias is `null` ?

Comment: Yes, Updated in the question. Please check.

Comment: I don't understand. Why does using `a=http://www.SSS.com/xx/xx` is the answer when namespace is null?

Comment: I tested it myself and it works. Are you using XPath 2 Extractor ?

Comment: Namespace is not null, it's the alias extracted which is null, so when you put a=http://www.SSS.com/xx/xx, you're saying I want to alias http://www.SSS.com/xx/xx with a, then you can use //a:ServerUrl as XPath expression

Comment: I can not modify the response from API and that was not the problem.

Comment: I am afraid you're not reading my response. I do not modify the response from API. All configuration is done in XPath 2 Extractor. You have accepted the other answer which is another way of doing what I described but using an old component that is not efficient. But it's up to you to decide.  I am sad for future readers of this question.